# Excel formula need formula for if value in A1>0 we need A1, but if value in A1 is 0, then we need the lowest value of A2 and A3

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
       A
1     5000
2     10000
3     12000
4
```

I need a formula for if value in A1>0 we need A1, but if value in A1 is 0, then we need the lowest value of A2 and A3.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, really:

> =IF(A1>0,A1,MIN(A2:A3))

If A1 > 0, show A1, otherwise show the minimum value of A2 and A3

---

See C1 (using A*) and D2 (using B*):

> [image]